# What is the difference between r+ and w+ modes in python?

Tags: python, coding-style, computer-science, programming-languages

Python related question

I tried playing with python but I couldn't make out the difference between r+ and w+.

Answer (score 0):

The r+ and w+ modes in Python are used to open a file for reading and writing. The main difference between these two modes is that the w+ mode will overwrite the file if it already exists, while the r+ mode will not.